# How to split a string by multiple separator in Typescript

Tags: typescript, split

i need to split a string by semicolon, colon, comma, cr, lf, clfr and whitespace. How can i do that?

Answer (score 6):

You can give the split function a regex to split it by.

A simple one looks like this.

```js
const text = "a,c;d e";

const splitted = text.split(/;|,| /);
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot but i have a problem: When I split a string with a linebreak like
"a
b"
the array I get is ['a', '', 'b'] but it should be ['a', 'b']. How can I fix this?

Comment: it would help if you would post a sample string to work with. :)

Comment: for example: `"a,c;d e\nx"` splits nicely with `/;|,| |\n/`, however `"a,c;d e\n x"` generates an empty string when split because there are 2 separators next to each other in the original string.

Comment: it's easy to just remove the empty strings from the resulting array with filter `splitted.filter(c => c)`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `/[,.;/ ]/` regex. It will split with all provided chars between []

```
"55,22.222;55 555".split(/[,.;/ ]/)

"15/01/2020".split(/[,.;/ ]/)
```

(Remove last empty space if you don't want to split by space => /[,.;/]/
)